# How to add child node in Firebase through android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to create child nodes. Whenever I try to add a child node it erases the existing node's data.

This is supposed to be the parent node:

```
databaseReference.child(usercurrent.getUid()).setValue(userInformation);
```

This is supposed to be the child node:

```
databaseReference.child(usercurrent.getUid()).setValue(driverInformation);
```

This is my intention:

```
User1{
      name: xyz
      number: 99...
      car1{ regno: 123
            make: ghj   }
      car2{.....}
     }
User2{..... }
```

Also, what is the use of push()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adress the car you want to add/update/remove:

```
databaseReference.child(usercurrent.getUid()).child("car1").setValue(driverInformation);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `push()` method to create a new unique random key each time you add a new `userInformation` object to the database like this:

```
databaseReference.child(usercurrent.getUid()).push().setValue(driverInformation);
```

Comment: Have also you tried my solution above, does it work?